# Hover img fadeIn next or fadeIn first img

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simplified what I am trying to achieve from my previous question.

This is a example of the script I am trying to write: [example](http://dev.web2works.co.uk/img-hover/) when you hover over the image you can see the problem. Possible fix with a delay?

I have a list of product each with 2-5 thumbnail images. I want to create a hover function that cycles through the images hiding/showing the next image.

I did try to stack the images using z-index although this was causing too much of a problem.

This is the hover function that I have put together so far:

```
$(".image_cycle img").live("hover", function(){

    if ($(this).next("img").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next("img").fadeIn("slow",function(){
            $(this).siblings("img").hide();
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().find("img:first").fadeIn("slow",function(){
            $(this).siblings().hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The else if not finding the first image and correctly fading in the first image. I would like this to work as a cycle constantly cycling through the hidden images

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this it would be much appreciated

Comment: Now it's more clear. I'll help you, give me some minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lightweight version of a cycle plugin which I've just whipped up:

```
jQuery.fn.HoverCycle = function(params){
            var defaults = {
                "Timeout": 1500,
                "FadeSpeed": "slow"
            };
            var opts = $.extend(defaults, params);
            if(isNaN(opts.Timeout)){
                throw "Hover Timeout value must be numeric";
            }
            (function(){
                var valid = true;
                if(isNaN(opts.FadeSpeed)){
                    opts.FadeSpeed = opts.FadeSpeed.toLowerCase();
                    valid = (opts.FadeSpeed == "slow" || opts.FadeSpeed == "fast");
                }else if(opts.FadeSpeed <= 0){
                    valid = false;
                }
                if(!valid){
                    throw "FadeSpeed must be either numeric and above zero, or either 'slow' or 'fast'";
                }
            })();
            return this.each(function (){
                var cycleTimer;
                var $firstImg = $currentImg = $(this).find("img:first");
                $(this).mouseenter(function(){
                    cycleTimer = setInterval(function(){
                        var $nextImg = $currentImg.next();
                        if($nextImg.length == 0){
                            $nextImg = $firstImg;
                        }
                        $currentImg.fadeOut(opts.FadeSpeed, function(){
                            $nextImg.fadeIn(opts.FadeSpeed, function(){
                                $currentImg = $nextImg;
                            });
                        });
                    }, opts.Timeout);
                }).mouseleave(function(){
                    clearInterval(cycleTimer);
                });
            });
        };
```

Apply it to the container of the images, so in this case, the  tag:

```
$(".image_cycle").HoverCycle();
```

It'll loop through the images in the order they're declared in the tag. You can override the fade speed and timeout duration via the constructor:

```
$(".image_cycle").Cycle({ "Timeout": 3000, "FadeSpeed": "fast" });
```

Where "Timeout" is the value in ms between it switching images, and "FadeSpeed" is the same permitted values as jquery's fade functions (ie "fast","slow", or a numeric value).

Answer (score 1):

You could better use the jquery cycle plugin.
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I looked at this first although it is more of a slideshow as I am only wanting this to only work on hover. It would be overkill if I have 10+ products all with active cycle plugin.

Comment: [code]
$('#s3').hover(
                function() {
                        $(this).cycle({
                            fx:     'fade',
                            speed:   400,
                            timeout: 300,
                            next:   '#s3',
                            pause:   0
                        });
                },
                function(){
                        $(this).cycle('stop');
                }
        );
[/code]

Maybe something like this will be my last resort.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/MtpPN/1/

here's an example, don't know exactly if that is what you want, but if it is a plugin would be overkill.